# Action bar: about up affordance icon

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

In **action bar**, there is an icon called "up affordance" showed below (the left-most one):

[image]

In my **Activity** `onCreate()` method, I have set the following things:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

**My Question is:**

1. how can I implement an `onClickListener` on this "up affordance" icon, so that when user click on it, the application will be navigated to the **upper level hierarchy** ?
2. how can I have only the **left arrow** without the android default icon of "up affordance" part on action bar?

Answer (score 4):

For implementing an onClickListener, instead just catch it in onOptionsItemSelected:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Do what you want here
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

For question two, [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home) page states:

> Using a logo instead of icon
>
> By default, the system uses your application icon in the action bar, as specified by the android:icon attribute in the  or  element. However, if you also specify the android:logo attribute, then the action bar uses the logo image instead of the icon.

Comment: Thank you, How about my 2nd question ?

Comment: Edited answer, don't think it's possible. Not sure though.

Comment: But how to set it transparent, how can I fetch the icon in Java code in my Activity method?

Comment: As the icon shown in the actionbar is your launcher icon, you'd have to set your application icon to be a transparent one - and thats definitely not recommended.

Comment: With ICS (and by extension, ABS version 4) you can call `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` and the back arrow will still appear next to the title text.

Comment: Edited my answer for question two - specifying a specific logo for the action bar, but Jake Warthon's answer is a better solution.

Comment: setDisplayShowHomeEnabled() doesn't show the arrow. To show the arrow use: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);